# How to make a website that Supports Google Chrome Add to Home screen?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-chrome

I have a question about how to make a website that supports Add to Homescreen in Google chrome.

That's mean some websites like web.whatsapp.com when clicking on the Add to home screen, Website shortcut add to my home screen but when I open it, it has different, It opens in fullscreen mode and hide Google chrome options.

please say how to create a website like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think they are called PWA (Progressive Web App) you can find information online on how to create those apps from scratch.